# Python Converting String into fixed Column Array

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array, serial-port

In case my question gets lost in the below, what I need to present to my home automation system is an array that I can retrieve information from on a cell by cell basis.

I am using the following code to read from a serial device that polls my home HVAC system (most of this is poorly copied from others' posts here):

```
import time
import serial
import StringIO

# configure the serial connections
ser = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyS0',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

input=1
while 1 :
        # Use static command to debug
        input = "stats"
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
        if input == 'exit':
                ser.close()
                exit()
        else:
                # send the character to the device
                # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
                ser.write(input + '\r\n')
                outputFCUData = ''
                # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
                time.sleep(1)
                while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                        outputFCUData += ser.read(1)

                if outputFCUData != '':
                        fcuArrayTemp = StringIO.StringIO(outputFCUData).read().splitlines()
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(0)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                        print fcuArrayTemp
                        exit()
```

If I were to poll the device without any formatting, the result would be:

```
stats
101 ON  070F 070F  Low  Heat OK 0
102 ON  069F 069F  Low  Heat OK 0
103 ON  069F 069F  Low  Heat OK 0
104 ON  069F 070F  Low  Heat OK 0
105 OFF 072F 064F  High Heat U5 0
OK
>
>
```

Which is when I `pop(0)` and the `pop(-1)`'s in the code to remove all but the 5 rows of information I want. For anyone curious, the first column (e.g. "101") are my fancoil names, followed by the status, the setpoint, current temp, fan speed, mode (heat/cool), error codes (e.g. 105 doesn't have a t-stat, so it has a `U5 error`) and then the last column are any errors sending commands to the device- none now, hence the "0".

So I want to take that output and convert it into an array so I can, for example, call a `fcuStatus[i][j]` command to pull the information out of cell(i,j).

What I get from my code is the following:

```
['101 ON  070F 070F  Low  Heat OK 0', '102 ON  069F 069F  Low  Heat OK 0', '103 ON  069F 069F  Low  Heat OK 0', '104 ON  069F 070F  Low  Heat OK 0', '105 OFF 072F 064F  High Heat U5 0']
```

Which is a 1 row, 5 column list.  I believe I should just need to read the elements from that list and add them to an array. So I add the code:

```
for element in fcuArrayTemp
    parts = element.split(' ')
    print parts
```

So now my output is:

```
['101', 'ON', '', '070F', '070F', '', 'Low', '', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['102', 'ON', '', '069F', '069F', '', 'Low', '', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['103', 'ON', '', '069F', '069F', '', 'Low', '', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['104', 'ON', '', '069F', '069F', '', 'Low', '', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['105', 'OFF', '072F', '064F', '', 'High', '', 'Heat', 'U5', '0']
```

Which is pretty close to what I want, except there are some extra columns added as a result of me splitting on a single blank when there is a double blank.

My code is sloppy and I have to believer there is a better way.  Can someone show me how to take the string information I receive in my `outputFCUData` variable and convert it to a functional array without the extra spaces?  There will always be 8 columns, but as fancoils are added to the system, the array could expand to 128+ rows.  Any of the above is because I don't know better, not because I'm trying to conform to a particular set of guidelines- any suggestions are more than welcome.

Edit- Wow- Radio- got me exactly what I was needing- thank you!

```
for element in fcuArrayTemp
    parts = element.split()
    print parts
```

So really the last part of this is how do I then take those organized lists and create a N row by 8 column matrix?  This errors out on no arguments given to append.  Adding "element" to the item to append (fcuArray.append(element)) doesn't get me there either.

```
fcuArray = []
for element in parts:
    fcuArray = fcuArray.append()
    print fcuArray
```

Thanks again

EDIT: Found a solution that works for me- posting it here for anyone else that is looking for something similar.  The trick was to add each line from the lists to my array as they were generated:

```
fcuArray = []
for element in fcuArrayTemp
    parts = element.split()
    fcuArray.append(parts)
```

Now I can report any value in the array by requesting the row and position.  For example, to report the name of the 3rd fancoil in my array I would ask for fcuArray[3][0] (namely "print fcuArray[3][0]" which would return "104".

Here is my complete code:

```
import time
import serial
import StringIO
import pprint

# configure the serial connections
ser = serial.Serial(
       port='/dev/ttyS0',
       baudrate=9600,
       parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
       stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
       bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
)

input=1
while 1 :
        # Use static command to debug
        input = "stats"
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
        if input == 'exit':
                ser.close()
                exit()
        else:
                # send the character to the device
                # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
                ser.write(input + '\r\n')
                outputFCUData = ''
                # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
                time.sleep(1)
                while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
                        outputFCUData += ser.read(1)

                if outputFCUData != '':
                        fcuArrayTemp = StringIO.StringIO(outputFCUData).read().splitlines()
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(0)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                        fcuArrayTemp.pop(-1)
                fcuArray = []
                for element in fcuArrayTemp:
                            parts = element.split()
                fcuArray.append(parts)
                print fcuArray
                print fcuArray[3][0]
                exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `element.split(' ')` to `element.split()` will suffice to remove extraneous columns.

```
>>> for element in fcuArrayTemp:
...     print element.split()
...
['101', 'ON', '070F', '070F', 'Low', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['102', 'ON', '069F', '069F', 'Low', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['103', 'ON', '069F', '069F', 'Low', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['104', 'ON', '069F', '070F', 'Low', 'Heat', 'OK', '0']
['105', 'OFF', '072F', '064F', 'High', 'Heat', 'U5', '0']
```